# how to write dataframe into csv file into minio bucket

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am working on a project. in which, i want to write spark dataframe data to a CSV file in MinIO bucket.
I have searched everywhere but didn't get any proper solution.
Please help me to achieve this.

I have tried many solutions but not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code:

```
String bucketName="my_bucket";
String filePath="files/my_file.csv"; 

List<Row> rowList = new ArrayList<>();
rowList = dataFrame.collectAsList();

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

String[] fieldNames = rowList.get(0).schema().fieldNames();
String headers = String.join(delimiter, fieldNames) + "\n";
baos.write(headers.getBytes());

rowList.stream().forEach(row -> {
                String[] arr = new String[row.length()];
                for (int i = 0; i < row.length(); i++) {
                    arr[i] = convertAllDataTypeToString(row.getAs(i));   //write one method to convert different data type to string 
                }
                String str = String.join(delimiter, arr) + "\n";
                try {
                    baos.write(str.getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());

MinioClient minioClient = // get your minio client here 
minioClient.putObject(PutObjectArgs.builder().bucket(bucketName).object(filePath).stream(bais, bais.available(), -1).build());


bais.close();
baos.close();
```